# What gets warmer faster: icewater or just ice?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, phase-transition, ice

**Revised Question** (07/07/20 14:00 UTC)

Working off of a suggestion by @GiorgioP:

> "Would it be fair to say that your question is about the difference of melting behavior of ice if surrounded by air or by water?"

*Sort of*. Maybe so, but I want to explain in longer form the practical question I'm trying to answer. Perhaps I was trying to be too technically precise and ended up diverging from what I actually needed to be asking.

**To keep the contents of the flask as cold as possible, is it better to leave ice in a thermos surrounded by (atmospheric pressure) air, and only add water at the time of consumption; *or* should you combine ice and water at the beginning and store them together?**

The practical goal is to maximize the volume of cold (nearly freezing) water that can be chilled and consumed using a fixed volume of ice and a real-world (not ideal) thermos/Dewar flask.

The goal of drawing out the scenarios is basically to differentiate between:

- Fill up the container with ice but no water, store it for some time, then fill it up with water and immediately drink the water; **or**
- Fill up the container with ice *and* water, store it for some time, then drink the water later.

Is there even a difference?

---

*Original problem setup follows. I'm not sure if this is still relevant.*

Given the following invariants:

- We have 20 identical, cubic, (water) ice cubes at the same temperature, same mass, volume, and density. If you need a measurement, assume they are similar to the size of a typical household freezer ice cube, except that they are precisely cubic in shape and completely solid with uniform density all the way through.
- We have a 1L [Dewar flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_flask) whose temperature is equalized with the surrounding air before beginning each experiment. It is *not* an ideal Dewar flask; it is a real one that you can buy off the shelf. I'm not sure how best to describe the properties of it, but for an approximation, if you fill this flask to the brim with ice cubes and then fill in the rest of the volume of the flask with cold water, there's still a little bit of ice left over about 48 hours later. Eventually, of course, all the ice will melt and the water will equalize its temperature with the room.
- Each experiment is conducted in a room at a constant 70 degrees Fahrenheit, and the room is large enough to keep the ice and the contents of the Dewar flask from significantly affecting the temperature of the room (obviously, there will be some small effect, but it wouldn't be measurable with common household instruments).

Consider the following two scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** 10 of the 20 ice cubes are placed into the Dewar flask; the flask is closed, then left alone in the room for 8 hours. Nothing else happens in the room, other than the ice melting.

**Scenario 2:** After taking measurements and resetting the experimental conditions, the remaining 10 of the ice cubes are placed in the Dewar flask, but then the flask is filled as much as possible with tap water at 60 degrees Fahrenheit. The flask is closed, then left alone in the room for 8 hours. Nothing else happens in the room, other than the ice melting.

At the end of the 8 hours in both scenarios, the flask is opened, and then:

1. The ice (if any remains) is removed without removing any significant amount of water, except whatever water coats the ice. The ice is then weighed.
2. The temperature of the melted water is measured as soon as possible using a thermometer.

---

**Original Questions** -- Possibly disregard these if they're no longer relevant given the Revised Question.

1. Will one or the other scenario result in a larger mass of ice remaining?
2. Will the temperature of the water be different between the two scenarios? If so, in which scenario will the water temperature be lower?
3. Which laws of physics point to the answers to the above questions?

I am not interested in a calculation of an exact answer for each, but if the scenarios are too "close" in behavior and would require a greater difference to be able to discern an answer without doing detailed mathematics, feel free to change the numbers to make the scenarios more dramatically different to demonstrate a concept.

Basically, I am trying to understand physics concepts that would help distinguish the behavior in these two scenarios. Actually crunching the numbers is not of interest to me in this situation, so please don't put in the effort to do so unless it's required to provide the answers.

Comment: I think you should try to distill a general question out of your example. As it is, there are details which is not clear how important are for your question. For example, why in scenario 1 do you put ice cubes in a dewar with air at 70 degrees Fahrenheit, while in scenario 2 you add tap water at 60 degrees? Is this difference of 10 degrees important for your question? Would it be fair to say that your question is about the difference of melting behavior of ice if surrounded by air or by water?

Comment: The problem is that we don't know how well the Dewar insulates. If it insulates perfectly (a reasonable approximation) then in S.1 the ice at the end equals the ice at the beginning. And for S.2 it becomes an adiabatic heat exchange problem, with phase change (some ice to water).

Comment: *I am not interested in a calculation of an exact answer for each* But only a detailed calculation can show us which S. leaves the most ice!

Comment: Upon reflection, I can understand the confusion of the posts here. I myself seem to have fallen short of setting up the problem in a way that's in touch with the actual situation I wanted to understand. I've made several edits to the question. Please check it out. Thanks. As with many things physics-related, formulating the right question turned out to be the hardest part of this for me.

Comment: It sounds like the easiest way to answer this question would be to test it empirically.

Comment: When you say "Fill up the container with ice but no water, store it for some time, then fill it up with water and immediately drink the water", what do you mean by "immediately drink it"? Aren't you going to let the water stand until it is chilled to the temperature you want?

Answer (score 1):

If the Dewar flask is an ideal insulator then in Scenario 1, no ice will melt at all.

But in Scenario 2, adding some water to the ice will make some of it melt (the more water added, the more ice will melt)

So for a perfect insulating Dewar flask, Scenario 1 will ALWAYS  leave the most ice. It's trivial, really...

But if the Dewar isn't perfect, the situation is more complicated.

Comment: Nitpick:  some ice will melt in Scenario 1 due to its absorption of heat from the ambient-temperature air remaining in the flask. But since the volumetric heat capacity of air is much lower than that of water, the amount of melting will be correspondingly smaller.

Comment: There's more to nitpick: heat capacity of the flask, e.g. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first case: the dewar is ideal, so almost no ice will melt, only the air in the dewar will go du 32°F
second case, if the water ist not to much, it will cool down to 32°F, how much ice is remaining depends only on the amount of water compared to ice.

Answer (score 0):

It is determined entirely by the rate of heat loss of the flask, which is determined by the difference in temperature of the Dewar flask with its surroundings. So long as there is a mix of water and ice, the temperature is the same, but if you put in ice much colder than 0deg, it will be able to warm until the ice starts to melt. At that point, the situation is identical to putting in a mix of water and ice.

Of course, neither will warm at all until the ice is melted. So if you mean, which will start to warm earlier, then adding water will melt some of the ice, and this will cause warming to start earlier.